# tar command with -zxvf not extracting contents as expected

Tags: linux, google-bigquery, odbc

(ubuntu 18.04)

I'm attempting to extract an odbc driver from a tarball and following [these instructions](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/Simba%20Google%20BigQuery%20ODBC%20Connector%20Install%20and%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf) with command:

```
tar --directory=/opt -zxvf /SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux.tar.gz
```

This results in the following output:

```
root@08ba33ec2cfb:/# tar --directory=/opt -zxvf SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux.tar.gzSimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/GoogleBigQueryODBC.did
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/docs/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/docs/release-notes.txt
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/docs/Simba Google BigQuery ODBC Connector Install and Configuration Guide.pdf
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/docs/OEM ODBC Driver Installation Instructions.pdf
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/setup/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/setup/simba.googlebigqueryodbc.ini
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/setup/odbc.ini
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/setup/odbcinst.ini
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery32_2.4.6.1015.tar.gz
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015.tar.gz
```

The guide linked to above says:

> The Simba Google BigQuery ODBC Connector files are installed in the
> /opt/simba/googlebigqueryodbc directory

Not for me, but I do see:

```
ls -l /opt/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1001 4096 Apr 26 00:39 SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux
```

And:

```
ls -l /opt/SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux/
total 52324
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1001      400 Apr 26 00:39 GoogleBigQueryODBC.did
-rw-rw-rw- 1 1000 1001 26688770 Apr 26 00:39 SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery32_2.4.6.1015.tar.gz
-rw-rw-rw- 1 1000 1001 26876705 Apr 26 00:39 SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1001     4096 Apr 26 00:39 docs
drwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1001     4096 Apr 26 00:39 setup
```

I was specifically looking for the .so driver file. All the above is on a docker container. I tried extracting the tarball locally on Ubuntu 18.04 (Same as my Docker container) and when I use Ubuntu desktop gui to extract by double clicking the tar.gz file and then clicking 'extract', I do indeed see the expected files.

It seems my `tar` command (`tar --directory=/opt -zxvf /SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_2.4.6.1015-Linux.tar.gz`) is not extracting the tarball as expected.

How can I extract the contents of the tarball properly? The tarball in question is the linux one on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers#current_odbc_driver).

[edit]
Adding screens of contents of the tarball per comments. I had to click down two levels of nesting to arrive at 'stuff':
[image]
[image]

Comment: What's inside of the embedded 32/64 bit `.tar.gz` files?

Comment: @stdunbar added screens now at the bottom of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you linked to do not match the contents of the file I found from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers).  The first `.tar.gz` contains two other .tar.gz files.  I looked into the 64 bit one and it has:

```
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/ErrorMessages/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/ErrorMessages/en-US/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/ErrorMessages/en-US/SimbaBigQueryODBCMessages.xml
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/ErrorMessages/en-US/ODBCMessages.xml
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/ErrorMessages/en-US/SQLEngineMessages.xml
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/ErrorMessages/en-US/DSMessages.xml
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/ErrorMessages/en-US/DSCURLHTTPClientMessages.xml
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/third-party-licenses.txt
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/lib/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/lib/libgooglebigqueryodbc_sb64.so
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/lib/cacerts.pem
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/lib/EULA.txt
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/Tools/
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015/Tools/get_refresh_token.sh
```

Your `.so` is in the `lib` directory.  Based on the instructions it looks like you need to extract this file (or the 32 bit if appropriate) and rename, in this case `SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015` to `simba/googlebigqueryodbc`.  The tar command is doing what it is told but the instructions are way off.

Comment: Agree instructions are either off or tricky to follow. I cannot seem to rename a file to simba/googlebigqueryodbc since it has a slash in it

Comment: Sorry - you'll have to first do a `mkdir -p /opt/simba` then `mv SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery64_2.4.6.1015 /opt/simba/googlebigqueryodbc` likely as root.